# Page 1 shows just a number where the rest show 'Page x of 4'

Tags: latex

The first page shows ust a centralised number, and the rest shows 'Page x of 4' with x being their respected page numbers. I want the first page to also be of this format, bu can't figure out why it's doing this

```
\lfoot{} % Define left footer


\rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}


\cfoot{}
```

Comment: Can you please make a [mre]? The first page probably uses another page style, so in addition to changing the `fancy` page style you will also have to adjust `plain` or `empty`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first page probably uses a different page style, for example `empty` or `plain`. You can also adjust this style:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\lfoot{} % Define left footer

\rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}

\cfoot{}

\author{names}
\title{text}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\lfoot{} % Define left footer
\rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}
\cfoot{}
}

\begin{document}



\maketitle

\lipsum


\end{document}
```